# Java returning stale data from oracle

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat, jdbc

I have a java web app that pulls data from an oracle database, and the other day I modified some rows of data using oracle sql developer.

Now the problem is Java keeps returning the old data as if it never changed, but if I run the exact same query in sql developer it returns the current (modified) data.

I don't have any caching enabled, I checked with OracleDataSource.getImplicitCachingEnabled() and OracleDataSource.getExplicitCachingEnabled() and both are false.

Is there some kind of cache built into Oracle itself that needs to be cleared ? I have been racking my brain over this for 2 days.

I tried starting/stopping and undeploying/redeploying the app with no change. I even tried restarting tomcat itself and that hasn't helped. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Do COMMIT in SQL Developer

Answer (score 5):

You most likely did not have `autocommit` on in SQLDeveloper, so the data had not been committed and was not visible outside the SQLDeveloper session.